# Tomcat errror! localhost didn’t send any data

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, localhost

I am installing tomcat with mysql + eclipse to run a simple web page with search function. I followed the example from here: https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/searchbook.shtml
However, when I submitted the form, error was displayed.
I changed the tomcat port from 8080 to 8085 so when I browsed the local host 8085, it also displayed error. Moreover, when I run another jsp file, the port shown is 8080 not 8085 as I set default.

I tried several solution on google and stackoverflow also but it did not work. I did not know the reasons why. Quite strangelly, I did the same with the example https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/searchbook.shtml from my computer at home. It worked without error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi Stenphen, my apology for uploading pictures. I just want to make sure that everyone to understand the problems i am facing now.

Comment: People will understand them better if you show us the problems 1) as text not as images, and 2) in the question itself.

Comment: You should show your code that is related to the question, not a link to another site (tutorial) and expect others to read and analyse what the code is doing.